# How do I make the parameters parsed by configparser visible to every .py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to parse parameters, vars by using configparser. However, I have to 
pass the instance to every .py, in order to get the parameters.

What is the most elegant way to make the parameters visible to every .py ?

Thanks!

Comment: For the most part, you don't. 80% of your code should be quasi-library-code which the remaining 20% invoke according to the options. The few options not sensibly covered by this (e.g. logging for `--verbose`) frequently have other solutions that don't require you to break scopes (to stay with the logging example: `import logging; logging.getLogger('mypackage.subsystem').addHandler(...)`). A few things for which this makes sense may remain, but they should be rare. So ask yourself: can't you go without super-global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have "config" module, which parses the options into a global variable (in that same module) which you then include in all places where you need it.

Admittedly though, I do agree with delnan's comment, avoid globals if it's possible as in general it will push you to design better code. Personally I don't find them evil, as delnan says there are some cases where they still make sense.